# Datastax cassandra driver skip null UDT fields

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Datastax Objectmapper provided way to update rows by merging columns by skipping update to not null fileds using

```
@Update(nullSavingStrategy = NullSavingStrategy.DO_NOT_SET)
```

However I have scenrio where my columns are UDT,and I want to have similar behvior for UDT fields too. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Also if there is no other way, only option is to write CQL statement from my POJO. Is there any utility method to write POJO to CQl or I need to manually go over fields and do null check and add them to update ?

Comment: first question - do you need to update fields of the UDT individually? or they always updated by `save` the all fields? If later, then I recommend to make UDT column `frozen`

Comment: I need to update individually as I need to merge with old state. Yes otherwise I use frozen. I dont want to do read and update ( by merging in applications)

Comment: Any other easy way to achieve it ? other that writing big update myself.

Comment: I really don't remember. I maybe would ask as well in the java driver mailing list or at datastax community site

Comment: Hey I have another scenario where I am storing Map<String ,String> when updating I have partial map and I want it to ovewrite or add new keys but not replace existing keys . Is there a way to achieve same using ObjectMapper ?

Comment: maybe only with custom queries